# NSData initWithContentsOfURL Error

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, cs193p

i'm trying to load an image from web. For initialize the Data i use this method:

```
NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageUrl];
```

but i get this error:

```
[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x817a4f0
2013-08-26 09:45:53.221 CorePhoto[1643:3f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x817a4f0'
```

And of course self.imageUrl is an NSURL property.

this is an example of imageUrl url:

```
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4016/4555417946_e6332481b3_b.jpg
```

this is the complete code of my method:

```
- (void)resetImage
{
    if (self.scrollView) {
        if (self.imageUrl) {
            //before to set the content, we reset it
            self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
            self.imageView.image = nil;
            [self.spinner startAnimating];
            dispatch_queue_t loadImageQ = dispatch_queue_create("load image thread", NULL);
            dispatch_async(loadImageQ, ^(void) {
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
                NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageUrl];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    if (image) {
                        self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
                        self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
                        self.imageView.image = image;
                        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                    }
                    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

what is wrong with my initWithContentsOfURL method? thanks
thanks

Comment: "And of course self.imageUrl is an NSURL property." No it's not. It's an __NSCFString according to the error. You need to create a URL from the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageUrl` may be defined as an `NSURL` property but you have set its value to an `NSString` instance. This may not give you a compiler warning in a number of cases and won't throw an exception until you try to use it.

Check where you set `imageUrl` and ensure you verify the type and create an `NSURL`.

Comment: Thanks, the error is where i have set the property, because i pass a string rather than an NSURL:

    NSURL *url = [[photo.photoURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

if i change this method into this :

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[photo.photoURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

works fine. thank and sorry for the stupid error XD.